# update rad ajax manager from codebehind

Tags: vb.net, radajaxmanager

Hi can someone help me how to call (or refresh) below control from code behind?

Currently it is working when I click my btnUpdate button. Along with I want to refresh the same usercontrol when I press another button also (ex: btnrefresh).

```
<telerik:RadAjaxManager ID="RadAjaxManager1" runat="server">
    <AjaxSettings>
        <telerik:AjaxSetting AjaxControlID="btnUpdate">
            <UpdatedControls>
                <telerik:AjaxUpdatedControl ControlID="Panel1" LoadingPanelID="RadAjaxLoadingPanel1" />
             </UpdatedControls>
         </telerik:AjaxSetting>
     </AjaxSettings>
     <ClientEvents OnRequestStart="RequestStart" OnResponseEnd="ResponseEnd" />
</telerik:RadAjaxManager>

<telerik:RadAjaxLoadingPanel ID="RadAjaxLoadingPanel1" runat="server" Skin="Default" />

<asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server" Width="100%">
    <uc:EmpEnrollment runat="server" ID="EmpEnrollment" />
</asp:Panel>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add another `AjaxSetting` for your `btnrefresh` in your `AjaxSettings` like below:

```
<AjaxSettings>
   <telerik:AjaxSetting AjaxControlID="btnUpdate">
      <UpdatedControls>
         <telerik:AjaxUpdatedControl ControlID="Panel1" LoadingPanelID="RadAjaxLoadingPanel1" />
      </UpdatedControls>
   </telerik:AjaxSetting>
   <telerik:AjaxSetting AjaxControlID="btnrefresh">
      <UpdatedControls>
         <telerik:AjaxUpdatedControl ControlID="Panel1" LoadingPanelID="RadAjaxLoadingPanel1" />
      </UpdatedControls>
   </telerik:AjaxSetting>
</AjaxSettings>
```